# Slim framework and application key-value variables

Tags: php, dependency-injection, scope, slim

I'm trying out the [Slim Framework](http://docs.slimframework.com/) and I'm having difficulty with using variables in the views. I understand the whole scoping aspect, but I'm not sure how to do this without repeatedly putting the variable in the array in the second parameter of the [`render()`](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Rendering) method.

Here's what I have:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->antiXSS = new \Zend\Escaper\Escaper('UTF-8');
$app->things = new \MyApp\Foo();

$app->get('/fruits', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('_header.php');
    $app->render('fruits.php');
});

// more of the same things and POST and PUT as well

$app->run();
```

In `fruits.php` and other views, I want to access Zend Escaper (`$app->antiXSS`) but I'm not sure how to go about doing that without doing anything repetitive.

#### Here's what I want to *avoid*:

```
$app->get('/fruits', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('_header.php', array(
        'app' => $app
    ));
    $app->render('fruits.php', array(
        'app' => $app
    ));
});
```

#### Another option I'd like to *avoid*:

```
// fruits.php

<h1>Fruits</h1>

<p><?php echo $GLOBALS['app']->antiXSS->escapeHtml($textAboutFruits); ?></p>
```

Both of these options seem rather messy and unorthodox. Obviously I've simplified the example to two variables (`antiXSS` and `things`) but there's many templates and variables that I'll be storing in `$app` (XSS prevention, session, CSRF token, to name a few).

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Slim singleton. Example:

```
$app->container->singleton('v', function() {return new Respect\Validation\Validator;});
```

http://docs.slimframework.com/di/overview/